# How to filter a polars DataFrame with list type columns

Tags: python-polars

I'm working with a polars DataFrame that contains columns with list type values. Here's how my DataFrame looks:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [['1', '3'], ['3'], ['1'], ['2']], 
    'b':[['8'],['6'],['6', '7'],['7']]
    })
```

I want to filter this DataFrame based on the 'a' column containing the list ['1']. I tried using the following code:

```
df.filter(pl.col('a') == ['1'])
```

but I get this error:

```
ComputeError: cannot cast List type (inner: 'Utf8', to: 'Utf8')
```

The filter works when the DataFrame has non-list type values, as in:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': ['3', '3', '1', '2'], 'b':['8','6','7','7']})
df.filter(pl.col('a') == '1')
```

How can I apply filtering to list type columns using polars? I'm not interested in solutions using pandas, only polars.

Comment: `df.filter(pl.col('a') == pl.lit([['1']]))` is supposed to work but needs fixing: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10138 - another workaround is to compare `.cast(pl.List(pl.Categorical)).hash()`

Comment: I've just checked that and now it actually works (polars version 0.20.3)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't do it directly because of how it broadcasts and casts Lists which have nested types.

One workaround is to make a column with the list in question and then filter like this:

```
df.with_columns(c=['1']).filter(pl.col('a')==pl.col('c')).drop('c')
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬────────────┐
│ a         ┆ b          │
│ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ list[str] ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════════╪════════════╡
│ ["1"]     ┆ ["6", "7"] │
└───────────┴────────────┘
```

Alternatively you can manually broadcast the underlying list like this:

```
df.filter(pl.col('a')==pl.Series([['1']]*df.shape[0]))
shape: (1, 2)
┌───────────┬────────────┐
│ a         ┆ b          │
│ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ list[str] ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════════╪════════════╡
│ ["1"]     ┆ ["6", "7"] │
└───────────┴────────────┘
```